# fabricjs toObject IIFE

Tags: fabricjs, javascript-objects

This code is from the fabricjs site:

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect();

 rect.toObject = (function(toObject) {
   return function() {
       return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
       name: this.name
    });
  };
  })(rect.toObject);
```

My question is: why did it have the immediately invoked function. Could't be written like this and it will have the same result:

```
   var rect = new fabric.Rect();
   rect.toObject = function() {
           return fabric.util.object.extend(rect.toObject.call(this), {
           name: this.name
           });
    };
```

Any difference between the 2 versions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1 > var rect = new fabric.Rect();
2 > rect.toObject = function() {
3 >   return fabric.util.object.extend(rect.toObject.call(this), { //here you are calling same toobject
4 >     name: this.name
5 >   });
6 > };
```

In line 3 you are calling `rect.toObject` which will refer to same overridden method `rect.toObject` which you defined now. So it will go on loop if you call it once. And will give you `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
1 > var rect = new fabric.Rect();
2 > rect.toObject = (function(toObject) {
3 >   return function() {
4 >     return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
5 >       name: this.name
6 >     });
7 >   };
8 > })(rect.toObject);
```

Here in line 8 `rect.toObject` is the original method which is passing as an external key. So in line 4 `toObject.call` will call the original method instead the overridden method. So it will extend with the return value of original `toObject` method with `name` property and will return the extended value.

That are object specific. If you want to override class method, you need to do

```
fabric.Rect.prototype.toObject = (function(toObject) {
  return function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
      name: this.name
    });
  };
})(fabric.Rect.prototype.toObject);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I got it.

The way it is written:
rect.toObject = (function ....to the end)
 will affect only the toObject method of this one instance named rect in particular and it will not affect any other Rect object, correct?

If we want it to affect all Rect, then we have to write:
Rect.prototype.toObject = (function ...to the end)
Correct?

Thank you